# If a change a Javascript string links on a page don't work, and I don't know why?

Tags: javascript, json, sharepoint

I've got a JavaScript file querying a SharePoint list. It's working great but returning an 'undefined' line which I can't resolve:

[image]

Fine, so I thought I'd just knock it out from the code.

If I use this string:

```
      txtTitle = txtTitle + "<p><a  href='/sites/it/ITInfrastructure/SitePages/Service%20Catalog‌​ue%20Devices.aspx?di‌​d=" + tempID + "'>" + tempTitle + "</a>" + "</p>";
```

The undefined vanishes BUT none of the links work, despite being the exact same links if I use this string which shows up the 'undefined'?!

```
txtTitle = txtTitle + "<p><a href='/sites/it/ITInfrastructure/SitePages/Service%20Catalogue%20Devices.aspx?did=" + tempID + "'>" + tempTitle +  "</a> - " + tempDeviceType + "</p>";
```

This is an example of a link: http://example.com/sites/it/ITInfrastructure/SitePages/Service%20Catalogue%20Devices.aspx?did=10

The code for the two js files I'm using (getDevices and getDeviceDetails) are below:

getDevices

```
function getDevices() {
var txtTitle = "";
var txtDeviceType = "";


   var query = "http://example.com/sites/it/ITInfrastructure/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Devices?select=ID,Title";

var call = $.ajax({
        url: query,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }       
    });


call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
    $.each(data.d.results, function (i, result) {

        var tempID = result.Id;
        var tempTitle = result.Title;
        var tempDeviceType = result.DeviceTypeValue;



        txtTitle = txtTitle + "<p><a href='/sites/it/ITInfrastructure/SitePages/Service%20Catalogue%20Devices.aspx?did=" + tempID + "'>" + tempTitle +  "</a> - " + tempDeviceType + "</p>";
        //txtTitle = txtTitle + "<p><a href='/sites/it/ITInfrastructure/SitePages/Service%20Catalog‌​ue%20Devices.aspx?di‌​d=" + tempID + "'>" + tempTitle + "</a>" + "</p>";



    });
    $('#devices').append($(txtTitle));
});
call.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
    alert("Error retrieving data: " + jqXHR.responseText);
});
}
```

getDeviceDetails

```
function getDeviceDetails() {
var txtTitle = "";
var txtName = "";
var txtOverview = "";
var txtAccessories = "";
var txtDevicetype = "";
var txtTypicalDeviceUsage ="";
var txtKnownSystemIssues ="";
var txtTrafficlight = "";
var imgDevicePicture = "";
var tempLCS2 = "";
var HTML = "<h3>Desktop</h3>";
var Laptop = "Y"
var Tabs="Y" ;  
  var query  
  = "http://example.com/sites/it/ITInfrastructure/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Devices?$expand=Priority&$filter=Id eq " + window.DeviceId + "";




var call = $.ajax({
        url: query,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }       
    });
call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
$.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {
        var tempID = item.Id;
        var NameofDevice = item.Title;
        var tempTitle = item.Title;
        var DeviceOverView = item.Description;
        var AccessDetails = item.Accessories;
        var DeviceKind = item.DevicetypeValue;
        var Usage = item.TypicalUsage;
        var DevicePriority = item.PriorityValue;
        var DeviceImage = item.DeviceImage;

        txtTitle = "<p>";  

        txtName = "<p>" + NameofDevice + "</p>" +  DeviceKind + "</p>";
        txtOverview = "<p>" + DeviceOverView + "</p>";
        txtAccessories = "<p>" + AccessDetails + "</p>";  
        txtDevicetype = "<p>" + DeviceKind  + "</p>";
        txtTypicalDeviceUsage = "<p>" + Usage + "</p>";
        txtTrafficlight = "<p>" + DevicePriority + "</p>";
        imgDevicePicture = "<img src='" + DeviceImage + "'>";

    });
    $('#devicedetails').append($(txtTitle));  
    $('#deviceoverview').append($(txtOverview));
    $('devicename').append(txtName);
    $('#devicekind').append(txtDevicetype);
    $('#deviceacc').append(txtAccessories);
    $('#deviceuse').append(txtTypicalDeviceUsage);
    $('#devicestatus').append(txtTrafficlight);
    $('#imageContainer').append("<img src='/sites/IT/ITInfrastructure/SiteAssets/"+txtTrafficlight.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '')+".png' />");
    $('.deviceimage').append(imgDevicePicture); 

});
call.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
    alert("Error retrieving data: " + jqXHR.responseText);
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have some charset problem. When I copy paste the lines:

```
    txtTitle = txtTitle + "<p><a href='/sites/it/ITInfrastructure/SitePages/Service%20Catalogue%20Devices.aspx?did=" + tempID + "'>" + tempTitle +  "</a> - " + tempDeviceType + "</p>";
    //txtTitle = txtTitle + "<p><a href='/sites/it/ITInfrastructure/SitePages/Service%20Catalog‌​ue%20Devices.aspx?di‌​d=" + tempID + "'>" + tempTitle + "</a>" + "</p>";
```

In notepadd++ with ANSI encoding, I get:

```
txtTitle = txtTitle + "<p><a href='/sites/it/ITInfrastructure/SitePages/Service%20Catalogue%20Devices.aspx?did=" + tempID + "'>" + tempTitle +  "</a> - " + tempDeviceType + "</p>";
//txtTitle = txtTitle + "<p><a href='/sites/it/ITInfrastructure/SitePages/Service%20Catalog??ue%20Devices.aspx?di??d=" + tempID + "'>" + tempTitle + "</a>" + "</p>";
```

Notice the "??" in the "Service%20Catalogue%20Devices" and "did" part. I think this is what make your link fail.

Comment: Thanks, so how should that URL be structured to avoid it failing?

Comment: If I do use the url without '+tempDeviceType +' I get the url http://example.com/sites/it/ITInfrastructure/SitePages/Service%20Catalog‌​ue%20Devices.aspx?di‌​d=11 when I hover over it and when I click on it, but I get that the page cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

This worked at knocking out the 'undefined':

```
txtTitle = txtTitle + "<p><a href='/sites/it/ITInfrastructure/SitePages/Service%20Catalogue%20Devices.aspx?did=" + tempID + "'>" + tempTitle + "</a></p>";
```